# Which SQL would work?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I am trying to work out the best DB structure and SQL for my application.

The scenario is this:

> Jim and John need to update their time sheets each week for different
>   projects. When they do this they use an html Form to insert their
>   hours based a date of the last day of the week.

This is fine and will insert a new row with NAME, Project, Date and Hours

However if jim and john do more hours than they expected and need to update their time sheet, I want them to be able to use the form and it will `UPDATE`the hours coloumn on the  DB if the name, project name and date are the matching the what has been submited.

SQL TO INSERT:

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO RESOURCE(NAME, DATE, PROJECT, HOURS) VALUES ('"+ name+ "', '"+ date+ "', '"+ project+ "','" + hours + "');
```

Work so far:

I have create the below DB structure on an SQLITE DB.

```
CREATE TABLE RESOURCE (
    name VARCHAR(16),
    date DATE,
    project VARCHAR(16),
    hours VARCHAR(16)
)
```

And I have create the following index to attempt to solve my issue.

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX myindex ON RESOURCE(NAME, DATE, PROJECT)
```

However, the problem is when jim updates his hours for the same date, project and hours as john, Johns row is replaced and only jims is left.

Hopefully I have explained this issue clearly, if not please let me know and I will supply whatever else is needed.

My question is: What can I change with either my SQL or my DB structure that would allow this aforementioned scenario to work?

Comment: I think you should have one unique column called resourceId and this will be identity of resources jim and john. Also how jim updates timesheet for john?

Comment: How would that resourceid column work? What would happen if there is multiple entries for jim or john on the same date for different projects and different hours?

Comment: Then you just update the rows based on resource id.

Comment: @AshReva Im not sure I under stand. How would the DB know which id to update?

Comment: This will sent from your webpage

Comment: What does your update statement look like?

Comment: sent from my webpage? From my webpage there is a JDBC connection using the SQL I have mentioned above. It doesn't specify a resourceid

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25759/discussion-between-ashreva-and-rhys)

Comment: Will you tell how user enter data? If Jim enters timesheet then how you insert data with his name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i got is that when jim/jhon enters his timing again an update query executes which update the whole records instead of updating jim/jhons own record. the main reason is that you don't have any unique key/primary key on your table that's why your query updates whole lot.

what you need to do is that have a key column and on the basis of that key you will update their records you will be using something like this in where clause

WHERE RESOURCE_ID = @RID //ID OF THAT PARTICULAR RESOURCE